# Is there a difference between perfect collinearity and multicollinearity?

Tags: regression, terminology, multicollinearity, assumptions

I've read that for multiple regression analysis there is an assumption of no perfect collinearity. Is that the same as multicollinearity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If your regressors are perfectly collinear, OLS estimation is impossible. In contrast, the more multicollinear (high collinearity but not perfect) your regressors the more inefficient your estimator, but OLS estimation under imperfect multicollinearity is very much possible and the OLS estimator is even consistent and unbiased. In your mind, you can usefully think of the effect of multicollinearity as that of decreasing your usable sample size.

Comment: Under imperfect multicollinearity, OLS is not only consistent and unbiased but also has minimum variance among unbiased linear estimators. That does not mean this variance is low, however.

Comment: Good point, but we need additional assumptions to establish that it is BLUE. Consistency and unbiasedness require that we assume only that the regressors are not perfectly colinear.

Comment: Absence of perfect multicollinearity in itself is not a sufficient assumption for consistency and unbiasedness, but I took other ones such as linearity for granted. I should have not done that, though.

Comment: Many of the negative statements made here about OLS for collinearity are incorrect or misleading: estimation *is* possible with collinear explanatory variables, within well understood limits; and consistency and bias theorems continue to hold when the model is viewed abstractly in terms of vector space projections.  The only thing that is affected by collinearity is *identifiability* of *some* of the parameters.

Comment: @RichardHardy: You are correct. I should have instead stated that we need 3 assumptions for consistency and unbiasedness of OLS in a predictive (not causal) context: 1) linearity, 2) no perfect collinearity, and 3) $E(u)=0$. To show OLS is BLUE we need to add the assumption of homoskedasticity.